# Segmentation fault error in C when editing int in while loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a C program which reduces a number into minimal factors. So far, I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    unsigned int parameter = 30, number, divisore = 2, contatore = 0, i = 0;
    int divisori[(number/2) + 1];
    number = parameter;
    while(divisore <= (number / 2)){
        if(number % divisore == 0){
            contatore++;
            number = number / divisore;
        }
        else{
            divisori[divisore] = contatore;
            contatore = 0;
            divisore++;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting segmentation fault. The problem seems to be linked to the line:

```
number = number / divisore;
```

As if I replace it with:

```
printf("New number: %d", number/divisore);
```

The program runs.
number/divisore will be an int as number % divisore is equal to 0, so it could not be because the operation returns a decimal number, but I cannot find what the problem is. Could you please help me out?

Comment: In `number = parameter;`, `parameter` is used uninitialized

Comment: Now `int divisori[(number/2) + 1];` number is used uninitialized.

Comment: @KeineLust Thank you! That was an error I made while I was trying to make the code minimal in order to post it here

Comment: Now `number` is used uninitialized :P

Comment: @KeineLust Whoops, that might be the problem hahah

Comment: Yeah, compile with warnings!

Comment: I have fixed the problem you pointed out and now the program works! Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: `main` should return `int`, `void main` is non-standard.

Comment: @n.m.Thanks for your comment! Could you please explain to me why I should use int instead of void in cases like this? I'm struggling to see why I should return an int, for example, in this specific scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted the integer `number` is declared but not initialized as the line `int divisori[(number/2) + 1];` is executed, leading to an error